# Finite Group acting on a Quasiprojective Scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

I was trying to do this problem. I was able to proove it in the case where X embeds in an open affine of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, but I have no idea about how to proceed in the general case. In particular I can't find an open affine cover of $G$-stable subsets.

Let $X$ be a scheme that is quasiprojective over a field $k$ and $G$
a finite group of isomorphisms of $X$ over $k$. Show that the quotient $X/G$ is a
scheme of finite type over $k$.

If anyone could be so kind to help me I would be very grateful.

Thank's to everybody.

Comment: This question is not research-level and is likely to be closed, perhaps it would be better suited for math stackexchange. Hint: show that if $X$ is quasiprojective then every finite subset of $X$ is contained in an affine open.